# Corrupted Images on S4 on Android Lollipop 5.0.1

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sd-card

I am experiencing issues with my S4 and the images I am taking on it.

Over the past week nearly all the images that I have taken have been corrupted when I go into Gallery or Photos to look at them.

I have had images sent to my via WhatsApp that I can save that do not become corrupted.

I'm using a 32gb sd card and I'm on Lollipop 5.0.1.

Is this a botched software update or a failing SD card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reccomended by [The Droid Guy](http://thedroidguy.com/) for Galaxy S5. I can only assume the solution can be proposed for the S4.

> **Lollipop Update Corrupted Photos in Galaxy S5 Sport**
>
> **Problem**: Good morning, I am hoping you are able to help. Two days ago, Sprint did a lollipop update on my Samsung Galaxy S5 Sport. Since
>   that time, about half of my pictures, are black, stating unsupported,
>   or media not found. I am heartbroken, as many of the pics are of our
>   new grandchild. I have tried everything to fix this, but to no avail.
>   I do have backup on, but, they are not there either. When removing sd
>   card, to put on computer, same issue remains. Please help. — Julie
>
> **Troubleshooting**: It appears like the update, somehow, has reached your microSD card and corrupted its contents. If your computer can’t
>   ready from the card either, then find some technicians in your area
>   who knows how to extract photos or files from corrupted SD cards.
>   There’s nothing much we can do about it because it’s more of a
>   hardware issue than anything else.

Read more [here](http://thedroidguy.com/2015/04/sprint-galaxy-s5-problems-errors-how-to-fix-them-part-2-106022#sgLXhSFQ8pzdOToI.99)

Comment: Thanks, i'm doing a full format of the SD card just now through Windows and if that doesn't work then i'll just buy a new 64GB MicroSD card. It's frustrating that a software update is affecting hardware in this way.

Comment: Lollipop has various issues like this. It's just unfortunate yours corrupted your SD Card, hopefully you didn't lose anything personal.

Comment: It doesn't look like i've lost too much, just photos and videos taken over the past week or so. I do have a friend who has had his entire MicroSD fried with **all** data lost!

Comment: Always good to hear, highly unfortunate for your friend though! technology is tempermental like that, i think thats why we love it so much. If you need anything else or if more needs to be added to gain an accepted answer let me know.